# Upload file to ftps from command line

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, curl, upload, ftps

I need to upload single file to ftp on port 21. I used this:

```
curl -T testFtpFile ftps://host -P 21 --user my_user
```

Bu i am receiving: `Failed to connect to host port 990: Connection refused`

How can I specify ftps port using curl?

Answer (score 4):

`ftps://` is *implicit* FTPS (port 990).

To use *explicit* FTPS (port 21), use [`--ssl` switch](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--ssl) (or even better [`--ssl-reqd`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--ssl-reqd) to enforce FTPS):

```
curl -T testFtpFile --ssl ftp://host --user my_user
```

---

*Note that [`-P` switch](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-P) toggles active/passive FTP connection mode. It does not specify a port number. And you do not need to specify a port number explicitly, if you are using the default port number (21).*